# How to display images from firebase storage web with v-bind in vuetify v-carousel?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js, firebase-storage

I have a VueJS project connected to a Firebase firestore and Firebase Storage.

After downloading the url of all images in firebase storage I haven't been able to bind those images to v-carousel, i don't know where is my mistake

here is my carousel :

```html
<v-carousel>
    <v-carousel-item v-for="image in images" 
                     :key="image.id" 
                     :src="image.src" />
</v-carousel>
```

and here  is my download url code :

```js
import { storage } from "@/firebase/init";
import { db } from "@/firebase/init";
import { images } from "@/firebase/init";

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            images: true,
        };
    },
    created() {
        var storageRef = storage.ref();
        storageRef
            .child("Carousel/")
            .listAll()
            .then(function (result) {
                let i = 1;
                result.items
                    .forEach(function (imgRef, i) {
                        // console.log(imgRef.toString());
                        imgRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
                            //  console.log(url)
                            let ImageUrl = url;
                            images.push({ src: ImageUrl + ".jpg", id: i });
                        });
                        i++;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            });
        console.log(images);

        itms.push(urls);
    },
};
```

init.js file:

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/storage";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    // ......
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// export default firebaseApp.firestore()

export default firebase.firestore();

export var storage = firebase.storage();
export let images = [];
```